# With Ruby, how do I combine an array of hashes to sum totals by date?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of arrays, each containing the number of orders by a given week. How do I merge this together to give a sum total for each week?

```
[
  [
    {:week_beginning=>Mon, 13 Feb 2017, :orders_total=>"1.00"}, 
    {:week_beginning=>Mon, 20 Feb 2017, :orders_total=>"3.00"}
  ], 
  [
    {:week_beginning=>Mon, 13 Feb 2017, :orders_total=>"2.00"}, 
    {:week_beginning=>Mon, 20 Feb 2017, :orders_total=>"7.00"}
  ], 
  [
    {:week_beginning=>Mon, 13 Feb 2017, :orders_total=>"3.00"},  
    {:week_beginning=>Mon, 20 Feb 2017, :orders_total=>"3.00"}
  ]
]
```

So that I end up with..?

```
[
  {:week_beginning=>Mon, 13 Feb 2017, :orders_total=>"6.00"}, 
  {:week_beginning=>Mon, 20 Feb 2017, :orders_total=>"13.00"}
]
```

Comment: are those date objects or strings?  can you update please.

Comment: They are date objects.

Comment: The totals are a string representation of a big decimal.

Comment: When you give an example it's helpful to assign a variable to each input object. Here, for example, `arr = [ [ { :week_beginning...`. That way readers can refer to the variable (`arr`) in answers and comments without having to define it. Also, all readers will refer to the same variable (as opposed to one whose name each makes up).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Letting `arr` be your array, you can do the following using  [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by).

```
arr.flatten.group_by { |g| g[:week_beginning] }.
    map { |k,v| { week_beginning: k, orders_total: v.sum { |g|
      g[:orders_total].to_f }.to_s } }
 #=> [{:week_beginning=>"Mon, 13 Feb 2017", :orders_total=>"6.0"},
 #    {:week_beginning=>"Mon, 20 Feb 2017", :orders_total=>"13.0"}]
```

Note that

```
arr.flatten.group_by { |g| g[:week_beginning] }
  #=> {"Mon, 13 Feb 2017"=> [
  #      {:week_beginning=>"Mon, 13 Feb 2017", :orders_total=>"1.00"},
  #      {:week_beginning=>"Mon, 13 Feb 2017", :orders_total=>"2.00"},
  #      {:week_beginning=>"Mon, 13 Feb 2017", :orders_total=>"3.00"}
  #    ],
  #    "Mon, 20 Feb 2017"=>[
  #      {:week_beginning=>"Mon, 20 Feb 2017", :orders_total=>"3.00"},
  #      {:week_beginning=>"Mon, 20 Feb 2017", :orders_total=>"7.00"},
  #      {:week_beginning=>"Mon, 20 Feb 2017", :orders_total=>"3.00"}
  #    ]
  #   }
```

Alternatively, you could use a *counting hash* (see the version of [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) where `new` takes an argument called the *default value*).

```
arr.flatten.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |g,h|
  h.update(g[:week_beginning]=>g[:orders_total].to_f) { |_,o,n| o + n }
end.map { |k,v| {week_beginning: k, orders_total: v.to_s } }
  #=> [{:week_beginning=>"Mon, 13 Feb 2017", :orders_total=>"6.0"},
  #    {:week_beginning=>"Mon, 20 Feb 2017", :orders_total=>"13.0"}]
```

`map`'s receiver is the following.

```
arr.flatten.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |g,h|
  h.update(g[:week_beginning]=>g[:orders_total].to_f) { |_,o,n| o + n }
end
  #=> {"Mon, 13 Feb 2017"=>6.0, "Mon, 20 Feb 2017"=>13.0}
```